# Why do some companies in the United States ask their employees not to share information regarding health plans?

Tags: health-insurance

Why do some companies in the United States ask their employees not to share information regarding health plans? I.e.,  why do some companies keep information regarding health plans confidential, accessible to the company employees only?

I'm surprised as typically company benefits are publicly accessible/advertised.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was a thing!  Have you run into this multiple times or just with one company?

Comment: @DoctorWhom so far just one

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at The Workplace? I can't see how an answer would relate to Health.SE...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about medical science.

Comment: [Where to ask questions about companies' policies on sharing information regarding health plans?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/339438/178179)